Executing shell script with a cron job
I can't execute a shell script with a cron job on WordPress (knowing that I can't use crontab). I can execute it with 'sh my_script.sh', but not with a cron job.
I've tried various scripts like this:
// Define the function that will execute your shell script
function execute_shell_script() {
    // Path to the shell file to execute
    $script_path = 'site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/github_install.sh';

    // Execute the shell script
    shell_exec($script_path);
}

// Schedule the execution of your function at a specific frequency
add_action('update_plugin', 'execute_shell_script');
if (!wp_next_scheduled('update_plugin')) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'update_plugin');
}

I want to pull from GitHub every day if there is an update.

You need to update your code to execute the shell script properly (ensure that the script file is in the correct location, and accessible from your project):
shell_exec("sh $script_path");

Make sure that your script itself has the executable permission
chmod +x script.sh

